How to move the cursor in a game like a normal mouse movement?
I use robotgo for mouse https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-vgo/robotgo#section-readme
I'm trying to write a macro for weapons in the game, I've done similar in lua before, but there I was working with the api of the mouse software.
In the game the cursor is centered and it is stationary, actually I need to move the cursor -20 by Y for example, I move it smoothly in the direction I want.
However, at the end of the downward movement, it tends to go up to the original position (only in the game).
How do I achieve the desired effect?
I'm testing in Rust game, I don't know how to simulate this behavior, so I'll record and attach a gif.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-vgo/robotgo"
    hook "github.com/robotn/gohook"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("--- Please hold MouseLeft---")
    hook.Register(hook.MouseHold, nil, func(e hook.Event) {
        if e.Button == 1 {
            sx, sy := robotgo.GetScreenSize()
            robotgo.MouseSleep = 100
            robotgo.MoveSmooth(sx/2, sy/2-20, 5.0, 5.0)
        }
    })

    s := hook.Start()
    <-hook.Process(s)
}


